# How to check conditions in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to open up a modal in my application, based on particular click it should open that respective modal.I tried ng-if and ng-switch concept but it didn't worked. So please help me..,
    Thanks!
    Here is my code..,

```
    <div ng-controller="projectsController">

        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click='toggleModal()' id="A">Bangalore</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click='toggleModal()' id="B">Mangalore</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click='toggleModal()' id="C">Mysore</a></li>
        </ul>


       <div ng-switch on="id">
           <div ng-switch-when="A">
                <modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='800px' height='50%'>
                <p>Modal Content Goes here</p>
                </modal-dialog>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="B">
                <modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='800px' height='50%'>
                <p>Second Modal Content Goes here</p>
                </modal-dialog>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
    /*app.js file*/
      myApp.controller('projectsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.modalShown = false;
      $scope.toggleModal = function() {
      $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
      };
    }]);
    //This is my directive in app.js i.e.,both controller and directive are in
    app.js file
     myApp.directive('modalDialog', function() {
      return {
       restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          show: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.dialogStyle = {};
          if (attrs.width)
            scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
          if (attrs.height)
            scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
          scope.hideModal = function() {
            scope.show = false;
          };
        },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
    };
    });
```

Comment: Your 3 links do exactly the same thing when clicked. Why should something different happen if they do the same thing? Have you read the documentation of ng-click and ng-switch?

Comment: so according to you how to change it with out using ng-click and ng-switch.

Comment: Did I say you shouldn't use them? What I said was: read the documentation of those directives. The first modal div is shown if `$scope.id` is equal to 'A'. You don't have any variable named `id` in the scope. And ng-click doesn't set any such variable.

Comment: So can you please give me the best example on how to use this kind of methods

Comment: The documentation is full of examples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the modal-dialog directive is coming from but it's possible the show attribute in it expects an expression.  You might want to change it to:

```
<modal-dialog show="modalShown === true" width="800px" height="50%">
```

Comment: sorry it's not working.<modal-dialog> is just an tag which i used here.

Comment: @amit it looks like you might be following the example over at http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/ - if so, did you add the directive into your code?  Without that directive, the modal-dialog tag will not do anything.